# ISCSI drive not mounting for use in windows server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, storage, iscsi

I Have IBM Storvize SAN device , which is the ISCSI target .

The IScSi initiator on the host windows server 2012 , is showing the status as connected to the volume on the san.

When the initiator connects the volume with its correct size is visible as a new disk in the disk management application .

Status shows connected on both the target and initiator .

The same volume shared on 2 ESXI host machines (VIA direct SAS cables )as well and is accessible

The host i am trying to connect is in a remote location and is accessible over the network

However i am unable assign a drive letter for this volume and hence not able to access the data on the volume from the initiator.

Any suggestions on solving this .

Comment: What are you trying to do? Shared SCSI disks like this generally means that you're trying to do a cluster, is this for a cluster between a VM and a physical device? Or are you trying to share data or something?

Answer (score 4):

Please ensure that you have **multipathing** and **multiple connections** enabled on iSCSI target side to be able to connect to the same iSCSI target from multiple hosts.

Keep in mind that it is not supported to use the same volume from multiple hosts at the same time unless you are using clustered file system http://darklight.pro/multiple-servers-accessing-the-same-iscsi-target-of-ntfsrefs-volume/.

I would not recommend sharing the same volume between different operating systems like Windows and ESX.

Answer (score 0):

When a server first scans a disk, it generally tried to claim it in such a way that other servers won't want to use it. The mechanism depends on the server, but this is a defense mechanism to prevent corruption. Computers that aren't in a cluster can't share SCSI LUNs.

Comment: They can actually. You have to have a cluster-aware file system or metadata manager but you might have no cluster for that purpose.

Comment: When I said "computers that aren't in a cluster", I assumed that it was obvious that this would include cluster-aware file systems etc. I meant "computers that don't have some sort of way of sharing SCSI disks".