# steps to troubleshoot server when it fails to attach and mount LUNs

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, storage-area-network, iscsi

How to troubleshoot when Windows Server 2012 R2 connected to SAN via iSCSI fails to attach and mount  the LUNs from the iSCSI target

Comment: This question would be better for Sever Fault or Super User.  It doesn't seem related to Information Security.

Comment: are there any entries in the eventlog?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ISCSI drive not mounting for use in windows server 2012](https://serverfault.com/questions/813743/iscsi-drive-not-mounting-for-use-in-windows-server-2012)

Answer (score 0):

I would at first look at the availability of the SAN from the Windows Server. Any possible firewalls that could block the connections
Then I would look into Windows Event Viewer to find iSCSI initiator log entries and see if there are any errors occurring.

Also, I'd like to have more information on the problem. E.g. How does the failure in Windows 2012 look? Are there any errors? What is the iSCSI target device etc